# PHP - Mysqli_query is successful, but return empty rows

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have a table full of names and I have a stored procedure that returns all of the names. However it is not doing what I expect it to do and I can't pinpoint the problem even with log. Instead of getting a drop down list of actual names, I'm getting a drop down of blank values as if I can actually select a value, but console.log displays a empty value, which I'm assuming means it's null

connection.php

```
<?php
    require 'credentials.php';
    include '../ChromePhp.php';

    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($con->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        ChromePhp::warn('something went wrong!'); // didn't reach here
    }
?>
```

This calls retrieveAllPokemonNames.php

```
  <?php 
    include '../database/retrieveAllPokemonNames.php';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "<option value= ".$row[0].">".$row[0]."</option>";
    }
  ?>
```

retrieveAllPokemonNames.php

```
<?php
    require 'connection.php';
    $sql = "CALL sp_selectAllPokemonName";

    if ($result = $con->query($sql)){
        ChromePhp::log('query is successful'); // output
        ChromePhp::log($result); // log outputs a Object { current_field: null, field_count: null, .....etc }
    }
?>
```

The SQL query works fine when I call it in phpMyAdmin's interface and `sp_selectAllPokemonName` is basically

```
Select * From PokemonName
```

which returns ~100 rows

Comment: You doesn't call any `fetch` function get records. So I think you need to change this line `ChromePhp::log($result);` to  `ChromePhp::log($result->fetch_assoc());`

Comment: Mmm but I also have a console.log on that client that shows that row is blank. So basically I'm getting a drop down list of blank values, which I assume means they are null